# Yeoman Generator not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I am trying to use Yeoman to scaffold a MEAN stack app with the meanjs generator.

After running `yo meanjs` the generator starts with its questions, then it begins to generate then errors out

```
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.0.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! v8-debug@0.4.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@0.4.6 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the v8-debug package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs v8-debug
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-debug
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/zlerp/Documents/development/test/7/npm-debug.log
zlerps-MacBook-Pro:7 zlerp$ node -v
v7.0.0
zlerps-MacBook-Pro:7 zlerp$ npm -v
3.10.8
```

This happens for other yeoman generators as well.

I'm using a FRESHLY WIPED Mac with OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

I used brew install to install node and git as well.

Any help is appreciated.